# I'm going to wipe a Windows 2008 server, but I want to be able to restore it just in case

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, backup-restoration, restore, system-restore

I have backed up everything with the Windows Server Backup program, but will this be enough? My company is going to completely wipe the computer that has the server, but in case they change their mind will I be able to restore the server (including the operating system)? Is there anything I should know before proceeding? Any advice or helpful sources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you create a Full server backup? If so then yes, you can completely restore the server.

Comment: I would be tempted to use the sysinternals disk2vhd to make a backup of the system.  This should permit you to boot the server within Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you use Linux much, but for this scenario I use a Linux live DVD, boot to it, then gzip the entire raw hard drive image (such as /dev/sda) onto external storage.

If you want to restore the server later, you do the reverse, overlay the system image over the hard drive.

We could go into the specifics if this approach is interesting to you.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Windows Server Backup is fully capable of performing a full server backup that can be used to perform a bare metal restore to the same or dissimilar hardware.

Comment: Good point.  This is just my preferred wheel since it handles any OS with the same mechanisms.